# Linearly separating a Gaussian Filter and calculating with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, convolution, gaussianblur

I have a `2d` `numpy` `array` containing `greyscale` pixel values from `0` to `255`. What I want to do is to create a `gaussian filter` **from scratch**. I have already written a function to generate a `normalized` gaussian `kernel`:

```
def gaussianKernel(size, sigma):
    kernel =  np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: (1/(2*math.pi*sigma**2)) * math.e ** ((-1*((x-(size-1)/2)**2+(y-(size-1)/2)**2))/(2*sigma**2)), (size, size))
    return kernel / np.sum(kernel)
```

which works fine:

```
>>> vision.gaussianKernel(5, 1.5)
array([[ 0.01441882,  0.02808402,  0.0350727 ,  0.02808402,  0.01441882],
       [ 0.02808402,  0.05470021,  0.06831229,  0.05470021,  0.02808402],
       [ 0.0350727 ,  0.06831229,  0.08531173,  0.06831229,  0.0350727 ],
       [ 0.02808402,  0.05470021,  0.06831229,  0.05470021,  0.02808402],
       [ 0.01441882,  0.02808402,  0.0350727 ,  0.02808402,  0.01441882]])
```

So then I created a basic `convolution` function to apply this `kernel` to each `pixel` and produces a `gaussian` blur:

```
def gaussianBlurOld(img, kSize, kSigma):
    kernel = gaussianKernel(kSize, kSigma)
    d = int((kSize-1)/2)
    gaussian = np.zeros((img.shape[0]-2*d, img.shape[1]-2*d))
    for y in range(d, img.shape[0]-d):
        for x in range(d, img.shape[1]-d):
            gaussian[y-d][x-d] = np.sum(np.multiply(img[y-d:y+d+1, x-d:x+d+1], kernel))
    return gaussian
```

Which works fine and blurs an image, however, as this code will be eventually running on a raspberry pi, I need it to be efficient and for it to be much faster. So thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513953/7434365) on a question I asked yesterday on how to speed up a `Sobel` edge detector, I tried to apply the same logic he gave to the `gaussian` filter. However, as the `function` will accept a `variable` size parameter for the `kernel`, it complicates things slightly from the set size of the `Sobel` kernel which is just `3x3`.

If I understand the explanation correctly, I need to first separate the kernel into `x` and `y` components which can be done by just using the top `row` and left `column` of the original `kernel` (obviously they are the same, but I decided to just keep them separate as I have the `2d` kernel already calculated). Below is the matrix separated:

[image: separated filter]

From these `row` and `column` vectors, I need to go through each value and multiply that `'window'` of the array by it element-wise. After each one, shifting the reduced size of the window along the array to the right. To show what I think I need to do clearer, these are the 3 different `'windows'` I am talking about for a small image with a `kernel` size of `3x3`:

```
          _______3_______
     _____|_2_______    |
_____|_1__|____|    |   |
|    |    |    |    |   |
|123,|213,|124,|114,|175|
|235,|161,|127,|215,|186|
|128,|215,|111,|141,|221|
|224,|171,|193,|127,|117|
|146,|245,|129,|213,|221|
|152,|131,|150,|112,|171|
```

So for each `'window'`, you multiply by the `index` of that window in the kernel and add that to the total.

Then, take that img which has had the `x` component of the `gaussian` kernel applied to it and do the same for the `y` component.

These are the steps I think I can do to calculate the `gaussian` blur much faster than using `nested` `for-loops` as above and here is the code that I wrote to try and do it:

```
def gaussianBlur(img, kSize, kSigma):
    kernel = gaussianKernel(kSize, kSigma)
    gausX = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1] - kSize + 1))
    for i, v in enumerate(kernel[0]):
        gausX += v * img[:, i : img.shape[1] - kSize + i + 1]
    gausY = np.zeros((gausX.shape[0] - kSize + 1, gausX.shape[1]))
    for i, v in enumerate(kernel[:,0]):
        gausY += v * gausX[i : img.shape[0]  - kSize + i + 1]
    return gausY
```

My problem is that this function produces the right 'blurring effect', but the output values are all between `0` and `3` as `floats` for some reason. Luckily, for some other reason, `matplotlib` can still display the output fine so I can check that it has blurred the image correctly.

The question is just simply: *why are the pixel values outputting between `0` and `3`???*

I have debugged for hours but cannot spot the reason. I am pretty sure that there is just a little scaling detail somewhere, but I just cant find it. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check the dtypes. If possible work with extended dtypes- uint64/int64/float64.

Comment: @Divakar I tried changing `gausX` to initialize as each of those `dtypes`, but it cant do the multiplication with the kernel when set to an `int` `dtype` and the `float64` didn't change anything.

Comment: I tried a simplified example, and seems to work: `image = np.zeros((30,30))`, `image[:,15:] = 10000.0`, `i2 = gaussianBlurOld(image, 9, 3.0)`, `plt.imshow(i2)` - this gives output images with higher values.

Comment: @VBB Sorry if I was unclear, function `gaussianBlurOld` works fine but is very *slow* as it is looping through the `array`. The function `gaussianBlur` doesn't loop through the `array` so should be *faster* and it is, but produces too small values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone interested, the problem was from the fact that The function `gaussianKernel` returned the `2d` `kernel` `normalised` for use as a `2d` `kernel`. This meant that when I split it up into its `row` and `column` components by taking the top `row` and left `column`, these components were *not* `normalised`.

To solve this, I just added a parameter to the `gaussianKernel` function to select `2` dimensions or `1` dimensions (both `normalised` correctly):

```
def gaussianKernel(size, sigma, twoDimensional=True):
    if twoDimensional:
        kernel = np.fromfunction(lambda x, y: (1/(2*math.pi*sigma**2)) * math.e ** ((-1*((x-(size-1)/2)**2+(y-(size-1)/2)**2))/(2*sigma**2)), (size, size))
    else:
        kernel = np.fromfunction(lambda x: math.e ** ((-1*(x-(size-1)/2)**2) / (2*sigma**2)), (size,))
    return kernel / np.sum(kernel)
```

So now I can get just the `1d` `kernel` with `gaussianKernel(size, sigma, False)` , and have it be `normalised` correctly. This means I can finally get the right blurring effect without `scaled` `pixel` values.